# Get Product name for Azure Resources using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I can get list of all the resources for a given subscription as

```
get-azresource | export-csv -path ResourceList.csv
```

I need the ProductName property for these resources. However the above command does not provide that information.

Is there a way to get this information preferably through powershell?

Comment: What do you mean by Product Name? Please, give some additional information.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I realized that on Azure for different resource types, different properties have different names. It does not make sense to get static property names such as ProductName for all types of resources.